# Teradata For Loop without Cursor

Tags: teradata, plsqldeveloper

How to define FOR LOOP without Cursor in Teradata?

Actually I'm having code like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST1()
BEGIN
DECLARE VAR1 VARCAHR(200); 
DECLARE VAR2 VARCAHR(200);
FOR FOR_LOOP1 AS CUR_NAME CURSOR FOR
DO
---------SQL STATEMENT-------
FOR FOR_LOOP2 AS CUR_NAME1 CURSOR FOR
DO
---------SQL STATEMENT-------
END FOR;
END FOR;
END;
```

I need to execute NESTED CURSOR or FOR LOOP in Teradata, by taking the output of first cursor value, I need do execute the second cursor.

Can any one guide me, please!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you worked on Oracle before :-)

Although this is possible in Teradata using exactly the syntax you provided it's not recommended as cursors are sequential by nature while Teradata is a parallel DBMS. Cursors are already evil, but nested cursors are even worse.

Most cursors processing data can be rewritten, e.g. using Windowed Aggregate Functions (best case), have a look at [George Coleman's blog](http://developer.teradata.com/blog/georgecoleman)

Can you provide the actual code?